# MS Word Not Recognizing Files in OneDrive when Offline

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive

So I write on a cheap remote laptop, for areas far from mobile data or wifi. I have another laptop in my office that is on wifi. I use OneDrive to sync the documents.

Everything works fine on my office laptop; it's always online.

On my remote laptop, when I'm offline:

- I open a OneDrive MSWord document *that is stored on the remote laptop* I get

> The directory name isn't valid.({file path})

- When I open {file path} in File Explorer, I get

> No Internet Connection

and am unable to edit the file at all.

When the remote laptop is online, everything is fine.

The only options I have available in File Explorer right-clicking a folder or the "OneDrive - Personal" icon are: Share, View Online, Choose which Drive folders to sync.

I'm on the Microsoft 365 Family Plan.

On the browser the file looks like this
[image]

Comment: You are positive that these documents that cannot be opened have actually been synchronized to OneDrive? Can you download them from OneDrive through a browser?

Comment: @Ramhound I synched all files before I left to go offline. I force synch by pausing OneDrive from the taskbar and then unpausing it and checking the log.

Comment: So are you able to download the file through a browser?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, when i'm online.

Comment: Can you crop a screenshot that indicates the status and most important a clear image of the file icon of the file in question

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the file to see if there are options on the screenshot, and in oneDrive settings, you can also make the file accessible even if you are not connected to the network.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of OneDrive and Windows do you have? These options are not available to me.

Comment: The only options I have available right-clicking a folder are : Share, View Online, Choose which Drive folders to sync

Comment: The same is true for right clicking on the OneDrive - Personal link in the navigation bar.

Comment: On a Microsoft 365 Family Plan.